# Passing a variable from one function to another in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I have 2 functions and i was wondering if it is possible to use a variable that is defined in 1 function, in another function. Basically I have the following code:

```
(function( $ ) {
     //On input
     $("#anid").on("input", function() {
            var variable = 'testing';
      });

      //On change
      $('#dropdown').change(function(){
            var variable2 = variable;
        });
})( jQuery );
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to declare your variable outside both functions, in a scope where they can both accesse:

Comment: I understand, but the new value is based on the on.input, as it is the value of a textfield. So i need to set the variable there i guess.. just not sure how to pass that to the change function. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare the var `variable` out of that context.

```
 var variable = 'initialValue';
(function( $ ) {
     //On input
     $("#anid").on("input", function() {
         variable = 'new Value'
      });

      //On change
      $('#dropdown').change(function(){
            //don't even need another one here..
            //variable is accessible from here
        });
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: I *think* the original poster is looking for `var variable` inside the main function rather than outside it.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be working. I was setting var variable = 'new Value';  before, which was why it was not working. Also; what is the difference in what @jonSG says and the code above? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'll delete this once you comment and say to do so as the answer above is fine.  If you do not need `variable` elsewhere, then it will be cleaner to do:

```
(function( $ ) {
   var variable = 'initialValue';

   //On input
   $("#anid").on("input", function() {
     variable = 'new Value'
   });

   //On change
   $('#dropdown').change(function(){
     //don't even need another one here..
     //variable is accessible from here
   });

})( jQuery );
```